# Two tasks in one click; Attach image/pdf & thumbnail of image/pdf, Adobe Acrobat Forms

Tags: javascript, forms, button, attachment, acrobat

I need major help with this one.  I will definitely Tip if you already have the knowledge or can figure this out for me.

In Adobe Acrobat Pro forms, I am trying to create a button that will let my tech insert fuel and other purchase receipts to the form when asking for reimbursement.  The button needs to be just a rectangle box, that when clicked, will open their desktop(windows) and let them select a file to add.

For example: If they select a gas receipt jpeg, it will show a thumbnail size pic of the receipt as well as attach the pic to the form.  I can then see the pic in my attachment view when reviewing the submitted form.  Also, a popup saying the attachment was successful would be nice too.

I actually have a button with the JavaScript created on a practice form I created, but it makes me choose the file two times.  I used Document javascript and run a javascript under button properties.  Apparently, there is a discrepancy somewhere in my script. Even though it works, the choosing the file twice thing is a problem.  I prefer to do both commands in one click.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you render.

On the button I chose Run A javascript; and put the following:

```js
event.target.buttonImportIcon();

if (app.viewerVersion < 11) {
    import_pre_11();
} else {
    import_11();
}
```

and then I went to Javascript Editor/Document Javascript; and put import_file and form the script I added the following.

```js
// Initialize attachment number
attachment_num = 1;

// Initial location of file attachment icon
// The x value is incremented below
var oFAP = {x_init: -72, x: -72, y: -72};  // Below lower-left corner of the page

function import_pre_11() {

    if (app.viewerType === "Reader") {
        app.alert({
            cMsg: "You must user Reader version 11 or later to attach files to this form.",
            cTitle: "Attach File Error",
            nIcon: 3,
            nType: 0
        });

        return;
    }

    // Prompt user to import a file
    app.alert({
        cMsg: "Click the OK/Open button after selecting the file from your system that you want to attach.",
        cTitle: "Attach File",
        nIcon: 3,
        nType: 0
    });
    
    try {
        var rc = this.importDataObject("Attachment" + attachment_image);

        if (rc) {
            attachment_num += 1;
            app.alert({
                cMsg: "Attachment successful.\r\rOpen the Attachments panel to access the attached file(s).",
                cTitle: "Attachment Successful",
                nIcon: 3,
                nType: 0
            });
        } else {
            app.alert({
                cMsg: "Attachment cancelled.",
                cTitle: "Attachment Cancelled",
                nIcon: 3,
                nType: 0
            });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        app.alert({
            cMsg: "Could not attach file.",
            cTitle: "Could not attach file",
            nIcon: 3,
            nType: 0
        });
    }
}

function import_11() {
    try {
        var annot = addAnnot({
            page: event.target.page,
            type: "FileAttachment",
            author: "Form user",
            name: "File Attachment",
            point: [oFAP.x, oFAP.y],
            contents: "File attachment on: " + util.printd("yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss", new Date()),
            attachIcon: "Paperclip"
        });

        if (annot) app.alert("Attachment successful.",3);
        oFAP.x += 18;  // Increment the x location for the icon   
    } catch (e) {
        app.alert({
            cMsg: "Could not attach file.\r\rPlease report this error.",
            cTitle: "File attachment error",
            nIcon: 3,
            nType: 0
        });
    }  
}
```

As stated before.  The button works but I have to pic the file/image two times.  I want both actions in one click.

Comment: Thanks for responding Chris.  I must admit, I am more confused than i was before.  I copied and pasted everything in the green you sent and it is worse than what i originally requested.   It is not leaving a thumbnail and its still takes me choosing my file twice to grab it.  If possible, please explain what has happened here.  Am I missing something?